# Java BlockingQueue<Runnable> Inconvertible Types

Tags: java, android, casting, polymorphism

I'm using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` in some code, and I supply it with a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`. I get a compiler error saying `can't resolve constructor`. So I tried casting `queue` explicitly to `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`. However, I'm getting a compiler error by the `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s constructor:

```
Inconvertible types, cannot cast PriorityBlockingQueue<MyRunnable> to BlockingQueue<Runnable>
```

This is happening even though `PriorityBlockingQueue` implements `BlockingQueue` and `MyRunnable` implements `Runnable`. I'm using Java 7 on Android.

**Code:**

```
public class Test {
    PriorityBlockingQueue<MyRunnable> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(...);

    //compiler error without cast
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(..., queue, ...);
    //compiler error with cast
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(..., (BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue, ...);

    public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {...}
```

**Temporary Solution:**

In order to get it to compile, I've changed the cast to `(BlockingQueue)`, but I get a unchecked case warning (which I suppressed). I know that I can make `queue` a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` but then I have to cast in a bunch of places throughout my code which I'd rather not do.

Is there something that I'm missing, or is the unchecked warning my best shot.

Comment: Note the difference between `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` and `BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable>`. The queue you are supplying is compatible with only 1 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterized types in Java are *invariant*, which means that `X<SubT>` is neither a subtype nor a supertype of `X<T>`. You expect them to be *covariant*, such that `X<SubT>` would be subtype of `X<T>`.

If that was true of Java's generic type system, it would actually be very impractical and cause type-unsafety. For example, your `ThreadPoolExecutor` wants a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` because it may place *any kind of* `Runnable` into it, not just your `MyRunnable`s. There is no such thing as `ThreadPoolExecutor<MyRunnable>`.

So, if your expectation were true, you'd pass in a queue which works only with `MyRunnable`s, but it would be asked to enqueue, say a `TheirRunnable`. This would have to break either when the item is enqueued, or when it is dequeued as a `MyRunnable`.

Comment: Yeah. No. It wouldn't break anything. You forgot about erasure :) It would break if the OP tried to use the queue for his own purposes *while using it as an executor queue as well*. Care to make a note of why it does allow the type cast and then work OK for bonus points?

Comment: I didn't forget about erasure. Either the fact that it is a `Queue<MyRunnable>` would never be exercised (only dequeueing `Runnable`s), or it would break with a `ClassCastException`. So it wouldn't break only in the case where using a `Queue<Runnable>` is a non-issue.

Comment: So is the unchecked cast the only way for me to go here (short of declaring `queue` to be a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`?

Comment: @Eliezer I don't exactly see what you are after, since the queue you supply should not be used from outside the `ExecutorService`. If you don't use the queue from the outside, then I really don't see a point in parameterizing with `MyRunnable`. If you *do* use it from the outside (specifically, *dequeue* items from it), then with the unchecked cast you lose type safety as you may dequeue a non-`MyRunnable`.

Comment: @Eliezer The only **safe** way of going about is making the queue a generic `Runnable` queue (or not providing a generic type at all). Anything else including the cast opens up possibilities of it breaking horribly in the future.

Comment: I'm not dequeueing (is that a word) items from it, but I am passing a custom `Comparator` to `PriorityBlockingQueue` that needs access to `MyRunnable` methods and fields. This is for a utility library, and users will never have access to `queue` or the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, so I'm pretty comfortable with the unchecked cast, but you never know. I've commented everywhere to be careful in that regard, but who knows who might be playing with it in the future.

Comment: It would be bulletproof if you put the Executor Service behind your own wrapper, which would only allow `MyRunnable`s to be submitted. Then the unchecked cast cannot do any damage.